# Error: OnCheckedChangeListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have red lines under setOnCheckedChangeListener and OnCheckedChangeListener.  The error message is telling me: Multiple Markers at this line - OnCheckedChangedListener cannot be resolved to a type - the method setOnCheckedChangedListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCheckedChangeListener(){})

```
package com.lifematters;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test1);

    //define Navigation Image Buttons
    final Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);



    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioAnswers1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group, int checkedId){

        final RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioA1);
        final RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioA2);
        final RadioButton radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioA3);
        final RadioButton radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioA4);

        if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
            DisplayToast("No, not at all");

        } else if (radioButton2.isChecked()) {
            DisplayToast("On some days");

        }else if (radioButton3.isChecked()) {
            DisplayToast("On more than half the days");

        }else {
            DisplayToast("Nearly everyday");
        }
    }

  });


  }

}
```

Comment: press **ctrl+shift+o** for import classes in your eclipse..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- Change to `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`
- Add this to the start of your class:

  ```
  import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
  ```

As for `DisplayToast`, add the following:

```
public void displayToast(String text){
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And change `DisplayToast` to `displayToast` in your code. Method names should start with a lower-case letter by convention. Only class names should start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you :).  Now I am getting errors for DisplayToast? The method DisplayToast(String) is undefined for the type new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){}

Comment: You seem to have copied the code from somewhere and left some parts. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, you had Toast in there twice but I got the problem fixed, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import

```
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

Answer (score 1):

Import these Two class/interface.

```
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
```

This code may help for OnChacked Changed

- `//buttonView.getId()` is used to get the ids of Button
- `//boolean isChecked` is used that button is Checked or not

  ```
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


  if (isChecked) {

      switch (buttonView.getId()) {

      case R.id.radioA1:
            DisplayToast("No, not at all");
          radioA2.setChecked(false);
          break;

      case R.id.radioA2:
          DisplayToast("On some days")
          radioA1.setChecked(false);
          break;

                  .....
                  .....


      default:
          break;
      }

  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

Just change

```
.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){...
```

to

```
.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){...
```

and it will be working!